# Flash - Random image display, no repeat

Tags: flash, image, random

I'm looking to display three images, chosen at random on load, throughout the duration of a banner ad.
Basically, these images are health tips displayed on post it's - as it plays, the post-it's fly off, revealing the next tip. I also need ensure that the images don't repeat.
I'm mostly a timeline guy, but I've been learning AS and have no problem getting one image to display randomly - however the three separate ones with no repeat is throwing me off.
My thoughts are to are to either
a) Put all the images on separate frame within 3 MC's, and somehow display a random frame within that clip on load, ensuring no repeat
or
b) Load the images into 3  separate MC's through and XML doc, and pick one at random.
Any thoughts or points in the right direction would be much appreciated.
EDIT - I should've clarified...
The images only appear one at a time - so I think each MC would only contain one of the 3 random images selected. So is it possible to load a random image into a MC, and then duplicate that MC without a chance of the image repeating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one way of doing this following your thoughts is:
Put the images in one mc.
Create an array containing the frame number corresponding to each image.
Shuffle that array to have a random order. 
Play image frame using the frame from the shuffled array.

To shuffle the array you could use something like this:

```
function shuffleArray(a:Array):Array {
    var copy:Array = a.concat()
    var length:int = copy.length;
    var result:Array = new Array(length);
    for(var i:int = 0; i<length; i++)
    {
    result[i] = copy.splice(int(Math.random() * (length - i)), 1)[0];
    }
    return result;
}
```

to use the method, simply:

```
var imgFrames:Array = [1,2,3];
trace( shuffleArray(imgFrames) )
trace( shuffleArray(imgFrames) )
trace( shuffleArray(imgFrames) )
```

Comment: ah, I see the output working perfectly - how do you apply it to the MC containing the images? i.e, I have the AS in an empty frame on the top layer - bottom layer contains a 3 frame MC with the images.

Comment: That would depend on your code, if you want to loop over the images or not. But you pull the current index from the array and then make a mc.gotoAndPlay(index)

Comment: Sorry if this is an idiotic question...but how do you pull the index? :) much appreciated

Comment: I got it - split xml into three separate files, called by individual swfs. Those swf's then go in my main banner. Thanks for the help!